# Binding dynamic multiselect step

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, dynamic-binding

I would like to bind multi-select dynamic step in a title of a chart but can't figure out how to do that.
This is the step:

```
"step_1": {
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "label": "Dataset_1",
                    "name": "Dataset_1",
                    "url": "/services/data/v40.0/wave/datasets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                }
            ],
            "isFacet": true,
            "isGlobal": false,
            "label": "Step 1",
            "query": {
                "measures": [
                    [
                        "count",
                        "*"
                    ]
                ],
                "groups": "{{column(step_2.selection, [\"value\"]).asObject()}}"
            },
            "selectMode": "multi",
            "type": "aggregateflex",
            "useGlobal": true,
            "visualizationParameters": {
                "options": {}
            }
        }
```

Is there a way how to reference the output of that filter? E.g. if I select the filter values `Value 1, Value 2, Value 3` I would like to see in my chart title `Viewing Value 1, Value 2, Value 3`.
I think it should be something like `{{column(step_1.selection, [\"xxxx\"]).asObject()}}` but I don't know how to reference the selected values.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps

for getting your selected value as string you use a syntax

> {{cell(Step_2.result, 0, \"Value\").asString()}}

This will result in string value that you can use as chart title
replace your label with the following line and it should work

> "label": "{{cell(Step_2.result, 0, \"Value\").asString()}}"